# $\mathbf{E}[X|Z=z]=\mathbf{E}[Y|Z=z]$ implies $X=Y$ a.s.?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, almost-everywhere

Suppose that $X,Y,Z$ are real-valued random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ such that for all reals $z$ such that $P(Z=z)>0$ it holds
$$
\mathbf{E}[X|Z=z]=\mathbf{E}[Y|Z=z].
$$
What can be said about $X$ and $Y$? In particular, is it true that $X=Y$ a.s. $P\upharpoonright \sigma(Z)$?

Comment: Not at all--Try Y=X+U with U centered and independent of Z. (Unrelated: Please replace every {z} by z.)

Comment: Mmh your argument is correct; but it seems to me that if the image of $Z$ is at most countable then the equality holds because $\sigma(Z)$ is generated by those sets.. I don't understand where is the mistake, putting together with your answer

Comment: Maybe $\mathbb{E}[X|Z]=\mathbb{E}[Y|Z]$ a.s., right?

Comment: Huh? Try (X,U,Z) uniform on {-1,1}^3.

Answer (score 2):

Just consider $X, Z$ and $Y, Z$, to be independent, $X$ and $Y$ can have any probability distribution as long as they have equal mean. Then your equality holds for all $z$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not a.s. equal.

Comment: And X and Y not almost surely constant.